# Obtaining Access Tokens From External Login

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, .net-core, identity

I'm modify my authentication from using Identity server to use the built in .net-core authentication.  I'm trying to obtain the Access Tokens From An external Login.  But when I go to obtain the User from the User Manager it returns null.  I'm using the OAuth Authorization Code flow to login.  I have a callback method which signs in and returns a JWT (I've omited some irrelevant code for simplicity)

```
[HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallback")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

    var user = await (result.Succeeded ?
            _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey)
        : this.CreateIdentityUser(info));

    var serviceProvider = HttpContext.RequestServices;
    var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<PublicAstootContext>();
    await _signInManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync(info);
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);

    return await GenerateJwtResponse(_jwtFactory.GenerateClaimsIdentity(user.UserName, user.Id, userId),
        _jwtFactory, _jwtOptions);
}
```

I create my User Identity like so:

```
private async Task<IdentityUser> CreateIdentityUser(ExternalLoginInfo info)
{
    string email = await this.GetEmailFromLoginInfo(info);

    //var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = email, Email = email };
    var signinResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);

    if (false == signinResult.Succeeded)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to Create User");
    }

    var addLoginResult = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
    if (addLoginResult.Succeeded)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        _logger.LogInformation("User created an account using {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
    }

    return user;
}
```

When I go to obtain the Third Party Access Token

```
var user = httpContext.User;
var userManager = sp.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
var userFromManager = userManager.GetUserAsync(user).Result;

var accessToken = userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(
                                userFromManager, "Coinbase", "access_token").Result;
```

**EDIT**

<s>I cannot find my User in the the UserManager.   How can I obtain my third party access token?</s>

It looks like my HttpContext.User and my UserManager is out of sync.

```
var user = httpContext.User;
var userManager = sp.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();

if(false == user.TryGetClaimByType<string>(AuthenticationRule.EMAIL_CLAIM_TYPE, out var email))
{
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
}
```

How can I Sync the HttpContext.User and the Usermanger so I can simply call:

```
var userFromManager = userManager.GetUserAsync(user).Result;
```

Comment: Have you configured JWT auth in Startup.cs?

Comment: @MichaelL. Yeah I've configured JWT Auth and logging in works fine, I just cant obtain the a thirdy party access token

Comment: Is you access token stored in your cookie? If so you should be able to pull the token out of the cookie along with the sub id, which should be your IdentityUser Id. Then use the user manager to log that person in. This is how I pull tokens out of the cookie `var authenticate = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Cookie");
            var accessToken = authenticate?.Ticket?.Properties?.GetTokenValue("access_token");`

Comment: @A.Hasemeyer I'm not using cookies I'm using JWT.  The External Authentication Token is stored in the User from the User Manager, however for somereason my ClaimsPrinciple does not Map back to my IdentityUser